# Using Vue Router within DataTables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to add links/buttons to rows in my DataTable, which take you to a vue route once clicked. Of course, trivially I could simply add a normal `<a>` link with `href="/item/${id}"`. But that bypasses the router and causes the whole page to reload

I came up with two solutions, both of which rely on setting `onclick` to execute some code:

1. In `route1`, I attach a function called `vueRoute` to the `window` object, which is just a reference to the vue method `route1`. This function can now be called from anywhere
2. In `route2`, I have the `onclick` fire a `CustomEvent`, and I have an event listener set to have it handled by the `route2` vue method

I am not comfortable with either solution. Even though they work, they seem very "hacky". What should I be doing instead?

```
// datatables column definitions
columns: [
  // route1
  {
      data: 'id',
      render: function (dt) {
          return `<a href="#" onclick="(function(){vueRoute('${dt}');})()">route1</a>`;
      },
  },
  // route2
  {
    data: 'id',
    render: function (dt) {
        return `<a href="#" onclick="(function(){document.body.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent('clickedEdit', {detail : ${dt} }));})() ">route2</a>`;
    },
  },
],

// vue methods
methods: {
  route1(id) {
    this.router.push('/item/' + id);
  },

  route2(evt) {
    this.router.push('/item/' + evt.detail);
  },
},

// on mount, set up route1 and route2
mounted() {
  window.vueRoute = this.route1;

  document.body.addEventListener('clickedEdit', this.route2);
},
```

A working example can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-simple-mgdhf1?file=src/components/ListView.vue

> **EDIT**: What I actually ended up doing was to switch to a headless table component (TanStack), which plays better with Vue than DataTables. But the solutions posted below by @Damzaky and @Moritz Ringler work fine if you need to use DataTables

Comment: What do you mean by causes the page to reload. I don’t see that happening in spa apps. I think you can use the router instance directly if you don’t want to go with the conventional link component

Comment: @SamsonIyanda If you have a pure link (eg: `<a href="/item/${id}">Go</a>` it bypasses the router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `@click` handler on the DataTable object:

```html
<DataTable
  ...
  @click="resolveRouteFromClick($event)"
>
```

The event will be a regular click event, so we need a recognizable dataset property for the id:

```
{
  data: 'id',
  render: function (idValue) {
    return `<a href="#" data-item-id="${idValue}">route3</a>`;
  },
},
```

The click handler just has to make sure that the id can be retrieved, ensuring that the click came from a link:

```
resolveRouteFromClick(e){
  const itemId = e.target.dataset.itemId
  if (!itemId) {
    return
  }
  e.preventDefault()
  this.router.push('/item/' + itemId);
}
```

Here it is in the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-simple-bk36uf?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FListView.vue)

---

Interestingly enough, just as background, the problem isn't even the connection between Vue and jQuery, but the way DataTables work, particularly that there is no event for a click on a cell or a click on a row, and that the renderer can only return HTML strings.

That's no surprise though, just how jQuery works, where data, view and behavior is not inherently linked, but you connect them as you see fit. So there is no cell-click event we could piggy-back on, because in jQuery, you write it yourself or it is not there.

The most efficient way to set the handler in jQuery would be to set the event on the table with a target filter:

```
$('.datatable').on('click', 'a[data-item-id]', function(){...})
```

The advantage is:

- only one event for all rows
- no need to add events when changing page or re-render
- code in render function stays minimal

And the above solution in Vue does the exact same thing, just without jQuery.

So I think this is the most efficient way to make it work in Vue, both in amount of code (maintainability) and performance.

Note that since DataTable requires jQuery to be globally accessible, it is also available in your Vue component, and you could put the given jQuery statement into a `mounted` hook, where you can access the Vue router in the callback. So instead of putting the router in global scope to use it on jQuery side, you would use an object already in there on Vue side. 
Still, as it is not necessary to mix jQuery into your Vue code, I would avoid it and go with the above Vue-only solution.

Comment: I have tested your solution and the one posted by @Damzaky with 10k items (which is orders of magnitude more than what I'm expecting for this dataset) and there's no noticeable performance degradation. I like your original answer best, it works fine as it is.

Comment: If I understand how this works correctly, the original answer still has the three advantages you listed in the update, right? Also I'm not sure what you'd put in the callback when using the jQuery event handler, as you'd have to access the Vue object outside of Vue somehow, which is something I struggled with, and the only solution I came up with was to attach something to the `window` object

Comment: Oh, yes, I added the jQuery part for context, to show that the proposed Vue approach has the same advantages as the best approach native to jQuery/DataTables, not as a solution. Sorry if that wasn't clear! I'll add it to the answer. As to performance, setting the callbacks manually for 10k items, I get ~15ms - that's negligible, your are right. Thank you for making me look at that! I'll remove that note from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say this is the best solution, but in my opinion, as far as I know there is no real "best" solution since datatable is using jQuery and you're using vue here (the DOM control is kind of inconsistent). From quick searching, I found no way to
render a vue component inside the `render` property for the datatable.

So my idea is different in that it **simplifies** the render function, and add the event listeners with `drawCallback` and use event delegation to attach the listener.

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback):

> Function that is called every time DataTables performs a draw.
>
> ... you might want to assign events to the newly created elements

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      columns: [
        ...
        {
          data: 'id',
          render: function (dt) {
            return `<a href="#" class="route3" data-item-id='${dt}'>route3</a>`;
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    drawCallback(settings) {
      const tableElm = document.getElementById(settings.sInstance);

      tableElm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const id = e.target.dataset.itemId;

        if (id) {
          this.router.push('/item/' + id);
        }
      });
    },
  },
...
<template>
  ...
    <DataTable
      :data="data"
      :columns="columns"
      :options="{
        drawCallback: drawCallback,
      }"
      class="display"
      width="100%"
    >
  ...
</template>
```

So I simply attach `data-item-id` to each links and then use parent's click event to do the router push (event delegation). I know this is not the best answer, but maybe this could be another option for you.

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-simple-s8mwuu?file=src/components/ListView.vue) is the forked sandbox if you're interested.

Comment: No solution can be "perfect" since you don't want vue and jquery manipulating the same DOM elements, but this is much more elegant, I think.

Comment: An alternative to using `drawCallback`, if one wants to go with this route, is to use the `draw` event that's fired by the datatable on every update (eg: `<DataTable ... @draw="yourHandler">`). The table can then be accessed through the event that's passed to the event handler

Answer (score 0):

It's understandable that you want to avoid hacky solutions. Here's a better way to handle this situation using Vue directives and a more Vue-centric approach.

1. First, you'll want to use the **v-html** directive to render the raw HTML for the DataTable column.
2. Next, bind a click event to the link with the **v-on** directive (or the shorthand **@click**), and call the Vue method with the row data as an argument.

Here's how you can modify your code:

1. Update the column definitions:

```
columns: [
  {
    data: 'id',
    render: function (id) {
      return `<a class="route1-link" data-id="${id}">route1</a>`;
    },
  },
  {
    data: 'id',
    render: function (id) {
      return `<a class="route2-link" data-id="${id}">route2</a>`;
    },
  },
],
```

2. Modify your mounted function to attach event listeners using Vue:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    // Attach event listeners to the route1-link and route2-link elements
    this.$el.querySelectorAll('.route1-link').forEach((link) => {
      link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.route1(event.target.dataset.id);
      });
    });

    this.$el.querySelectorAll('.route2-link').forEach((link) => {
      link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.route2(event.target.dataset.id);
      });
    });
  });
},
```

3. Remove the previous **window.vueRoute** and **document.body.addEventListener** lines in the **mounted()** function.

With these changes, you are now using Vue's built-in functionality to handle the routing and click events, making the code more maintainable and less prone to errors.

Comment: I don't like this answer because: 1) it uses `$nextTick` (which would be executed every  time anything changes, not just the DataTable component), 2) it makes Vue add event listeners to elements dynamically generated by DataTables, which you generally want to avoid doing, and 3) it adds event listeners for every single button, so you're looking at a ton of event listeners with a large table